# Files disappear from azure blob storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Web app records a file into an azure blob storage:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

byte[] bytes = new byte[message.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(message.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
```

These files are meant to be available for later download (and the web app keeps track of every file it saves.

The files are disappearing after a certain time in the blob. I didn't put my finger exactly on how long they last, but they do disappear within days. The smallest file I saw was 114 bytes (and vast majority are meant to be about the same size), some files can be in the Megabytes and even hundreds of Megabytes if the situation warrants it.

Is there a way to check how/why/when these files were deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step would be to configure monitoring on the blobs to see if there are any delete requests - you can see how to configure the monitoring here. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/

Comment: Thank you. I got this set up, now logs get recorded and everything. Very cool. I also found out where the files went: one of the devs was clearing the whole blob when working on the logic behind these files being generated and recorded.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [Storage Analytics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343270.aspx) to find out the delete requests.